# Simulating <%#Bind(...) %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

ASP.Net:

In code-behind I can simulate `<%# Eval("Property")%>` with a call to `DataBinder.Eval(myObject,"Property");`

How do I simulate a call to `<%# Bind("Property")%>` ?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataBinder.`**`GetPropertyValue(`**`myObject,"Property"`**`)`**

Comment: Does this do the two-way data binding in the same way as <%Bind... ?

Comment: No. Two-way binding is a bit more complex and is handled internally by the ControlBuilder class which uses the ExpressionBuilderContext, ExpressionBuilder, DataBindingCollection, DataBinding, and  BoundPropertyEntry classes to process <%# Bind("Property") %>